# This happens when i try installing packges with apt

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-20.04

This happens anytime i try install a package. I really don't have an idea what is going on. I have tried to re-install python2.7 but I still get the same error messages.

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libffi-dev is already the newest version (3.3-4).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libpython2-stdlib
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 45 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up libpython2-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.17-2ubuntu4) ...
Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.18-1~20.04.3) ...
Linking and byte-compiling packages for runtime python2.7...
python or pycompile not found in public_modules.rtinstall hook.
dpkg: error processing package python2.7-minimal (--configure):
 installed python2.7-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python2-minimal:
 python2-minimal depends on python2.7-minimal (>= 2.7.17~rc1-1~); however:
  Package python2.7-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python2-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python2.7:
 python2.7 depends on python2.7-minimal (= 2.7.18-1~20.04.3); however:
  Package python2.7-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python2.7 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7-minimal
 python2-minimal
 python2.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```